# restoring weights of an already saved Tensorflow .pb model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have seen many posts about restoring an already saved TF models here, but none could answer my question. `Using TF 1.0.0`

Specifically, I am interested in seeing the weights for `inceptionv3` model which is publicly available in `.pb` file [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/tensorflow_inception_v3_stripped_optimized_quantized.pb). I managed to restore it back using a small chunk of Python code and can access the graphs high-level view in `tensorboard`:

```
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile

INCEPTION_LOG_DIR = '/tmp/inception_v3_log'

if not os.path.exists(INCEPTION_LOG_DIR):
    os.makedirs(INCEPTION_LOG_DIR)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    model_filename = './model/tensorflow_inception_v3_stripped_optimized_quantized.pb'
    with gfile.FastGFile(model_filename, 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        _= tf.import_graph_def(graph_def,name='')
    writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(INCEPTION_LOG_DIR, graph_def)
    writer=tf.summary.FileWriter(INCEPTION_LOG_DIR, graph_def)
    writer.close()
```

However, I failed to access any layers' weights.

```
tensors= tf.import_graph_def(graph_def,name='')
```

returns empty, even if I add the arbitrary `return_elements=`. Does it have any weights at all? If yes, what is the appropriate procedure here? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this code to print your tensor's value :

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.run('your_tensor_name')
```

you can use this code to retrieve tensor names:

```
    op = sess.graph.get_operations()
    for m in op : 
    print(m.values())
```

Comment: @thanks @vahid for the answer. So the returned value is the weight of a tensor? i.e.: `print sess.run('mixed_6/join/concat_dim:0') ` returns 3. How can we interpret this?

Comment: as a follow up, could you have a look at my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45408463/printing-values-weights-for-all-dtype-float32-in-tensorflow

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between restoring weights and printing them. The former one denotes that one would like to import the weight values from already saved ckpt files for retraining or inference while the latter may be for inspection. Also `.pb`  file encodes model parameters as tf.constant() ops. As a result, the model parameters would not appear in tf.trainable_variables(), hence you can't use `.pb` directly to **restore** the weights. From your question I take that you just want to 'see' the weights for inspection.

Let us first load the graph from `.pb` file.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile

GRAPH_PB_PATH = './model/tensorflow_inception_v3_stripped_optimized_quantized.pb' #path to your .pb file
with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
  print("load graph")
  with gfile.FastGFile(GRAPH_PB_PATH,'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    sess.graph.as_default()
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
    graph_nodes=[n for n in graph_def.node]
```

Now when you freeze a graph to `.pb` file your variables are converted to `Const` type and the weights which were trainabe variables would also be stored as `Const` in `.pb` file. `graph_nodes` contains all the nodes in graph. But we are interested in all the `Const` type nodes.

```
wts = [n for n in graph_nodes if n.op=='Const']
```

Each element of `wts` is of NodeDef type. It has several atributes such as name, op etc. The values can be extracted as follows -

```
from tensorflow.python.framework import tensor_util

for n in wts:
    print "Name of the node - %s" % n.name
    print "Value - " 
    print tensor_util.MakeNdarray(n.attr['value'].tensor)
```

Hope this solves your concern.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I came back to check whether I can assign new values to my tensors when there are in a `tf.constant() ops` mode using tf.assign? here is my full question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50961959/tf-assig-to-a-protocol-buffer-frozen-model-in-tensorflow

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to get the names of tensor.

[tensor.name for tensor in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]

Comment: thanks, @Beta. But my question was to find a way to retrieve the weights, it just returns a huge list of all the tensors: `[[u'mixed_10/join/concat_dim', u'mixed_9/join/concat_dim', u'mixed_8/join/concat_dim',...]`

Comment: @Amir: From your question it seems you were trying to call particular name of weights. But it might be the case that they were named differently. That's why I mentioned that code. Valid gave a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just small utils to print .pb model weights:

```
import argparse

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import tensor_util


def print_pb_weights(pb_filepath):
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.GFile(pb_filepath, "rb") as f:
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

    for node in graph_def.node:
        if node.op == 'Const':
            print('-' * 60)
            print('op:', node.op)
            print('name:', node.name)
            arr = tensor_util.MakeNdarray(node.attr['value'].tensor)
            print('shape:', list(arr.shape))
            print(arr)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('pb_filepath')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print_pb_weights(args.pb_filepath)
```

Comment: Will it work with those `.pb` files saved in `TF v2` using https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model ?

Comment: If saved_model is just .pb with some aditional metadata stored in separate files, I think yes.

Comment: tried it and doesn't work. `tf.gfile.GFile()` is completely changed in TFv2