# Printing values (weights) for all dtype=float32 in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, type-conversion

Is there an easy way to print the value of a `dtype=float32` without `placeholders` and `feed_dict`? This process is awkward and needs to be defined for every operation individually. Say I have `inceptionv3` model with hundreds of operations:

```
 op = sess.graph.get_operations()
    for m in op : 
    print(m.values())
```

as these and some of them are mixed:

```
...
(<tf.Tensor 'pool_3:0' shape=(?, ?, ?, 2048) dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'pool_3/_reshape/shape:0' shape=(2,) dtype=int32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'pool_3/_reshape:0' shape=(1, 2048) dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'softmax/weights_quint8_const:0' shape=(2048, 1008) dtype=quint8>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'softmax/weights_min:0' shape=() dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'softmax/weights_max:0' shape=() dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'softmax/logits/MatMul_eightbit_reshape_dims:0' shape=(1,) dtype=int32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'softmax/logits/MatMul_eightbit_reduction_dims:0' shape=(1,) dtype=int32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'softmax/logits/MatMul_eightbit_reshape_pool_3/_reshape:0' shape=(2048,) dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'softmax/logits/MatMul_eightbit_min_pool_3/_reshape:0' shape=() dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'softmax/logits/MatMul_eightbit_max_pool_3/_reshape:0' shape=() dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'softmax/logits/MatMul_eightbit_quantize_pool_3/_reshape:0' shape=(1, 2048) dtype=quint8>, <tf.Tensor 'softmax/logits/MatMul_eightbit_quantize_pool_3/_reshape:1' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'softmax/logits/MatMul_eightbit_quantize_pool_3/_reshape:2' shape=() dtype=float32>)
(<tf.Tensor 'softmax/logits/MatMul_eightbit_quantized_bias_add:0' shape=(1, 1008) dtype=qint32>, <tf.Tensor 'softmax/logits/MatMul_eightbit_quantized_bias_add:1' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'softmax/logits/MatMul_eightbit_quantized_bias_add:2' shape=() dtype=float32>)
(<tf.Tensor 'softmax/logits/MatMul_eightbit_quantize_down:0' shape=(1, 1008) dtype=quint8>, <tf.Tensor 'softmax/logits/MatMul_eightbit_quantize_down:1' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'softmax/logits/MatMul_eightbit_quantize_down:2' shape=() dtype=float32>)
(<tf.Tensor 'softmax/biases_quint8_const:0' shape=(1008,) dtype=quint8>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'softmax/biases_min:0' shape=() dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'softmax/biases_max:0' shape=() dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'softmax/logits_eightbit_quantized_bias_add:0' shape=(1, 1008) dtype=qint32>, <tf.Tensor 'softmax/logits_eightbit_quantized_bias_add:1' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'softmax/logits_eightbit_quantized_bias_add:2' shape=() dtype=float32>)
(<tf.Tensor 'softmax/logits_eightbit_quantize_down:0' shape=(1, 1008) dtype=quint8>, <tf.Tensor 'softmax/logits_eightbit_quantize_down:1' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'softmax/logits_eightbit_quantize_down:2' shape=() dtype=float32>)
(<tf.Tensor 'softmax/logits:0' shape=(1, 1008) dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor [] shape=(1, 1008) dtype=float32>,)
```

Is there an easy way to print the value of all of these float types at once?

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint([out
  for op in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations() if op.type != 'Placeholder'
  for out in op.values() if out.dtype == tf.float32])
```

Feed dicts are standard python dictionaries so they should not appear as graph operations.

**EDIT**

To get their values, you need to run them:

```
out_val = sess.run([out
  for op in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations() if op.type != 'Placeholder'
  for out in op.values() if out.dtype == tf.float32], 
  feed_dict=my_feed_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks @user1735003, This will print only operations having `dtype=float32`: Here is my output: `... <tf.Tensor 'softmax/logits_eightbit_quantize_down:2' shape=() dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'softmax/logits:0' shape=(1, 1008) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'softmax:0' shape=(1, 1008) dtype=float32>]`
 Now, how am I gonna be able to print their values?

Comment: @Amir I updated my answer to point out that you need to run the output in a session to get their values.

Comment: many thanks, @user1735003. This comes back to my first question now! how do we define the `feed_dict` to be general for all those different float types with different shapes :D